# Can I explicitly specify the NavigateUrl on a hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net, .net, hyperlink

Asp.Net is awfully clever and tries to resolve the `NavigateUrl` of a Hyperlink relative to the control it is in or relative to the application root if you put ~/ at the start.

But I have a situation where I want to explicitly set the url to a relative path and I don't want it to 'help' me at all.

Hyperlink's navigate url and HtmlAnchor's href property both exhibit this behaviour.
Is it possible to stop this behaviour - or will I have to generate the markup by hand and not use a control?

**e.g.** 
I have a user control in folder `[appRoot]/foo/bar` that contains `asp:Hyperlinks`.
I am using the control in the page `[appRoot]/myPage.aspx`.
I want the `href` property of the hyperlinks, when rendered, to be exactly equal to `'donkey.gif'`.

But if I write the following

```
 <asp:Hyperlink runat="server" NavigateUrl="donkey.gif" />
```

then the rendered href will be `'foo/bar/donkey.gif'`.

For complicated reasons that I would rather not go into here, using "~/donkey.gif" is not an option.
Also, I cannot use `ResolveUrl(string url)` to generate an absolute urls.

Comment: I have not got your question clearly, can you show us, where you are trying to specify the NavigateURL Explcitly ?

Comment: How do you expect `NavigateUrl="donkey.gif"` to ever resolve to `images/donkey.gif` ? Where does images come from?

Comment: @Dan Diplo - My mistake.  Question has been editted / corrected

Comment: lol at the use of quotes: 'help' me it is so helpful! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you simply use a HTML anchor (without the `runat="server"` attribute)? E.g:

```
<a href="relative.htm">link text</a>
```

**Update**: if you don't want to lose the functionality of the HyperLink control, you could create a control deriving from `HyperLink` and override the `AddAttributesToRender()` method (this is where the NavigateUrl is resolved).

`HyperLink.AddAttributesToRender()` looks like this:

```
protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    ...
    string navigateUrl = this.NavigateUrl;
    if (navigateUrl.Length > 0 && base.IsEnabled)
    {
        string str = base.ResolveClientUrl(navigateUrl);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, str);
    }
    ...
}
```

Custom HyperLink control:

```
public class MyHyperLink : HyperLink
{
  protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  {
    if ((base.Enabled && !base.IsEnabled) && base.SupportsDisabledAttribute)
    {
      writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Disabled, "disabled");
    }
    base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
    if (this.NavigateUrl.Length > 0 && base.IsEnabled)
    {
      writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, this.NavigateUrl);
    }
    if (this.Target.Length > 0)
    {
      writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Target, this.Target);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this is the way I am having to go.  It is frustrating because I set a few properties (such as Target, Tooltip etc) in code which makes generating the overall markup onerous.

Answer (score 13):

A more simple solution would be to set the href attribute of the asp:hyperlink instead of using NavigateUrl property:

```
hyperlink1.Attributes("href") = "exactpath.gif"

hyperlink1.Attributes("href") = ResolveUrl("~/dir/page.aspx")
```

As of .NET4 you can also just set the href attribute directly like this:

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" href="donkey.gif" />
```

Comment: +1. I really love when something so simple solves the problem!

Comment: Thanks for this - I was setting the NavigateUrl property in my code-behind and it wasn't working. Setting the href Attribute worked.

Comment: A couple of things with this on .Net 4 a) I can't get it to work as advertised as the HyperLink still adds the relative path to the link, even though the markup shows the href as "google.com" or whatever and b) I get a compiler error for `myHyperLink.Attributes("href")`. The compiler error is resolved by using `myHyperLink.Attributes["href"]`. I won't edit this post as it seems some people have had success with this approach. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360537/asphyperlink-navigate-url-adding-relative-path-to-the-url) helped me.

Comment: It does work with .Net 4 - just make sure you are not using both the href and the the NavigateUrl property in the html. Use one or the other.